# How to hightlight a string in generated text report?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a java program that searches for a given string in multiple files and generates an output text file with info about the searched string.

How can I highlight that string in my text report?

Comment: Use HTML for output text? Then you'd have all formatting options of HTML to highlight whatever you want.

Comment: HTML for generated .txt file?

Comment: You mentioned "text file" not "plain text file". HTML is in fact text/html. Plaintext as it is has very limited "highlighting" options - surrounding with * or something might work - but decreases readability a bit.

Comment: true, can't it be highlighted like done in notepad or notepad++,I mean the style,when we use ctrl+f there. * wont work for me.

Comment: No can do. Ctrl+F changes format for whole file. Maybe you could consider two files? One plain and one highlighted (html)?

Comment: As already mentioned, this cannot be done with a plain .txt. file.  You will need either a marked-up file, like HTML, or maybe a rich text file.  Just to give another option (since I don't know your requirements) you could try Apache POI and output to a .doc file, and **bold** your desired text.